# Uvs Unwrapping in a Staircase Made of Quads

Tags: uv, workflow

I have a 5/7 that I want to bake a normal map to and then texture, but when I unwrap with proper seams, or even if I do smart uv, it simply projects in a staircase made of uniform quads and some tris splitting them in half.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Images would make your question much clearer, please [edit] your question and add some that would help clarify your issue. Thanks

Comment: i cant add images and post text at the same time. is it possible to comment with images?

Comment: You may [edit] your question to add images using the inbuilt tools provided and also any additional information needed at any time. There is an edit link in my comment as well as below your question. :)

Comment: i tried to use an image but the best i could do was a discord link